# Regex não está funcionado com file_get_contents

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, file-get-contents

Estou com um problema sobre regex e venho aqui pedir ajuda a vocês.

Estou tentando obter um valor de um arquivo `.chr` pela regex, mas ela não retorna nenhum match, acho estranho pois já testei em motores de regex online e deram match.

```
 $conteudo = file_get_contents($chart);

 preg_match('/valorLoteIni=./', $conteudo, $matches);

 var_dump($matches); exit;
```

No caso estou tentando pegar o valor de valorLoteIni

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu já tinha dito, já testei em sites, e o resultado foi o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como os senhores podem ver, a regex está funcionando.

Espero que me ajudem, obrigado e até mais.

EDIT.

Pra quem quiser testar vou postar o arquivo: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SuOd6ZvBz1xxNculHgy-eN2-coOBQW3a/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Se colocar um `echo $conteudo;` mostra alguma coisa?

Comment: mostra o conteudo do arquivo

Comment: Que estranho.. poderia testar com o arquivo?

Comment: Usei um mesmo arquivo .chr para pegar os dados.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pelo seu retorno man. Me ajudou bastante

Comment: Esse arquivo .chr é texto puro, como se fosse um .txt?

Comment: Postei o arquivo no post

Comment: arrumei o link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O arquivo `.chr` possui um tipo de codificação que adiciona "espaços" entre os caracteres ao ser lido pelo `file_get_contents()`. Veja como é retornado no navegador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que esses espaços não são espaços comuns, são espaços de algum tipo de código que é interpretado pelo navegador como um espaço. Logo, não adiantaria colocar espaços na regex, pois não os reconheceria.

Neste caso, você consegue capturar o padrão adicionando um ponto `.` entre cada letra da string buscada, porque o ponto na expressão regular representa *qualquer caractere*. Logo, não importa que caractere seja esse dos espaços, o padrão irá casar.

Ou seja, troque o padrão por este:

```
'/v.a.l.o.r.L.o.t.e.I.n.i.=.{2}/'
```

Ficando:

```
preg_match('/v.a.l.o.r.L.o.t.e.I.n.i.=.{2}/', $conteudo, $matches);
```

Acrescentei o `{2}` para que o último ponto case pelo menos 2 caracteres após o sinal de `=`.

Comment: Valeu cara!!! funcionou aqui. MUITO obrigado mesmo!!

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei uma solução melhor para o problema!

É só converter o arquivo para UTF-8 usando a função `mb_convert_encoding()`!

Segue o codigo abaixo:

```
    $conteudo = mb_convert_encoding(file_get_contents($chart), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE');

    preg_match("/valorLoteIni=[0-9]{1-4}/", $conteudo, $match);

    $replacement =  'valorLoteIni='.$valor;

    $regex = preg_replace("/valorLoteIni=\d/", $replacement, $conteudo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom por padrao o PCRE trata a string como uma linha unica, mas mesmo assim eu acredito que deveria casar o resultado da sua regexp.

Bom tente utilizar o modificador de multiline e veja se conseguer obter algum resultado.

```
preg_match('/valorLoteIni=./m', $conteudo, $matches);
```

se o valor de valorLoteIni for sempre um numero inteiro voce pode mudar para

```
preg_match('/valorLoteIni=\d/m', $conteudo, $matches);
```

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta. Adicionei o m na regex mas não deu resultado algum.

Comment: E possivel compartilhar o dump da variavel `$conteudo`?

Comment: Acho melhor eu compartilhar o arquivo, não?

Comment: A flag `m` [só afeta o comportamento dos marcadores `^` e `$`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php): sem o `m`, eles correspondem ao início e fim da string, com o `m`, eles também correspondem ao início e fim de uma linha. Mas como a regex não tem `^`, `$` ou `\n`, usar ou não o `m` não faz diferença ([veja](https://ideone.com/tnAd3T)). O problema deve ser o conteúdo do arquivo, que deve ter caracteres invisíveis no meio da string, ou algo assim...